# How to write vectors in abbreviated set notation?

Tags: notation, vectors, vector-analysis

I was wondering whether anyone knew how to write a vectors in abbreviated set notation to express the solutions to this question:

*"Determine all values of x, y, z ∈ R such that (x, y, z) is perpendicular to both a = (1, 1, 1) and b = (−1, 1, 1)."*

Letting n=[x , y, z], I figured out the two simultaneous equations (we have not covered cross product yet)

1. x + y + z = 0
2. -x + y + z = 0

However, the question wants us to express the answer in the form of {...|c ∈ **R**) which I am unsure how to do.

I understanding expressing the answer in the regular notation would be something like {(x, y , z) ∈ **$R^3$** | x=0 and y=-z}.

Thank you very much for your help guys! Much appreciated :)

Comment: If you find a vector $(l,m,n)$ perpendicular to $a$ and $b$, then {$c(l,m,n)|c\in \mathbb R$}$=${$(cl,cm,cn)|c\in\mathbb R$} is a set of vectors perpendicular to $a$ and $b$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I understand your explanation for a given vector; however, in this case, I have infinite solutions, so how would I express that in the abbreviated set notation?

Comment: $(l,m,n)$ is a given vector; {$c(l,m,n)|c\in\mathbb R$} is an infinite collection of vectors, since $\mathbb R$ is infinite;  what are the solutions you have?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. In this case, I think my solution for vectors which are perpendicular to a and b must satisfy l=0 and m= -n. However, if I write, {c(l,m,n)|c∈R}, wouldn't that mean l is allowed to equal 0?

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I'm not sure I understand your question -- the solutions are {$(0,c,-c)|c\in\mathbb R$}

Comment: Thank you for your help J.W. Tanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many vectors $(x,y,z)$ perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,1,1)$;

if you find one of them, say ($l,m,n$), then all vectors in the set {$(cl,cm,cn)|c\in \mathbb R$} are solutions.

You found a solution $(0,1,-1),$ so {$(0,c,-c)|c\in\mathbb R$} are solutions.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your patience. I finally understand what you mean. Hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The *[reduced (row) echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form)* of the *[homogeneous linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems)* above (equations 1. and 2.) is
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, $$
which tells us that $x = 0$ and $y = -z$. By convention, $z$ is a free variable, so every solution is of the form
$$ \{ (0,-c,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid c \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help!